# wkhtmltopdf commandline error :CSRF form field is missing

Tags: c#, pdf, command-line, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf to generate PDF in my application.I used command lines for that.While genarating the pdf i got this issue.

```
CSRF form field is missing.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: Idunno.AntiCsrf.PotentialCsrfException: CSRF form field is missing.
```

This is my code line with commands.I tried to bind csrf as custom-header.but the error is same.Please help me how to add this missing thing into my command.

```
            string command = string.Format("--custom-header _csrf {2}  --post BYPASS yes  --cookie ehrem8585 {1} --cookie  __CSRFCOOKIE {2}   --disable-smart-shrinking --orientation Landscape {0} ", pageWidthHeightSwitches.ToString(), cookieVal,csrfCookie);
```